# Using the cblas_chpr function

Tags: c, cblas

I'm having issue when I tried to use the cblas_chpr() function from the cblas library to calculate the correlation matrix of a float complex vector.

After downloading the [Lapack v3.10.0 Library](https://github.com/Reference-LAPACK/lapack/archive/refs/tags/v3.10.0.tar.gz) from netLib.org, I compiled it and copied the **libcblas.a**, **liblapack.a**, **liblapacke.a**, **librefblas.a** and **libtmglib.a** files to my project and make sure that the libraries are linked correctly.

According to the description, the cblas_chpr function calculates alpha * x * conjg(x') + A and stores the result in A.

The function is defined as:

```
void cblas_chpr(CBLAS_LAYOUT layout, CBLAS_UPLO Uplo,
                const CBLAS_INDEX N, const float alpha, const void *X,
                const CBLAS_INDEX incX, void *A);
```

Where the parameters are:

- layout - this is an emun and the two possible inputs are CblasRowMajor and CblasColMajor.
- Uplo - this is an enum and the two possible inputs are CblasUpper and CblasLower.
- N - The order of matrix A and the number of elements in vector x.
- alpha - The scaling factor that vector X is multiplied by.
- X - Vector X.
- incX - Stride within X. For example, if incX is 7, every 7th element is used.
- A - Matrix A. Overwritten by results on return.

The body of my function is as followed:

```
   /* Number of elements */
   int Ne = 10;


   /* Set the parameters */
   CBLAS_LAYOUT layout = CblasColMajor;   /* Layout is column major */
   CBLAS_UPLO Uplo = CblasUpper;          /* Upper triangle of the matrix */
   CBLAS_INDEX N = Ne;                    /* Number of elements in vector X */
   float alpha = 1.0;                     /* No scaling, alpha = 1.0 */

   /* The vector X */
   float complex * X = malloc(Ne * sizeof(* X));

   /* Set values of X - for illustration purpose only */
   for(int i = 0; i < Ne; i++)
   {
      X[i] = CMPLXF(i, i + 1.0);
   }

   CBLAS_INDEX incX = 1;                  /* Use data from every element */

   /* The correlation matrix is a Ne x Ne matrix */
   float complex ** A = malloc(Ne * sizeof(*A));

   for(int i = 0; i < Ne; i++)
   {
      A[i] = malloc(Ne * sizeof(*A[i]));
   }

   cblas_chpr(layout, Uplo, N, alpha, X, incX, A);

   float complex print_val = A[0][0];
   printf("%+.10f %+.10f", crealf(print_val), cimagf(print_val));
```

However, the program crashed with the **No source available for "chpr_() at 0x55555555e70b"** error.

I'm guessing that my input parameters are not correct. CBLAS is a wrapper for the Fortran BLAS Library.

Has anyone encountered this error before and know how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question in case someone else ran into the same issue. A should be a 1D array of size N * (N + 1) / 2. Also, the value each element in array A must be initialize to zero. Otherwise, the result will be wrong. Read the description for the cblas_chpr() function for why this is the case.

```
/* Number of elements */
int Ne = 10;

/* Set the parameters */
CBLAS_LAYOUT layout = CblasColMajor;   /* Layout is column major */
CBLAS_UPLO Uplo = CblasUpper;          /* Upper triangle of the matrix */
CBLAS_INDEX N = Ne;                    /* Number of elements in vector X */
float alpha = 1.0;                     /* No scaling, alpha = 1.0 */

/* The vector X */
float complex * X = malloc(Ne * sizeof(* X));

/* Set values of X - for illustration purpose only */
for(int i = 0; i < Ne; i++)
{
  X[i] = CMPLXF(i, i + 1.0);
}

CBLAS_INDEX incX = 1;                  /* Use data from every element */

/* Initialize the array that store correlation matrix */
int size_A = Ne * (Ne + 1) / 2;
float complex * A = malloc(size_A * sizeof(*A));

for(int i = 0; i < size_A; i++)
{
    A[i] = 0.0;
}

cblas_chpr(layout, Uplo, N, alpha, X, incX, A);

/* Print the first value of the result */
float complex print_val = A[0][0];
printf("%+.10f %+.10f", crealf(print_val), cimagf(print_val));

free(X);
free(A);
```